# Meaning of "while still very young"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> Frollo himself had a very interesting
>   history. From childhood, his parents had
>   trained him for the priesthood. **While still
>   very young**, he had been sent away to study.
>   He learned to read Latin, Greek, and Hebrew.
>   By age 18, he believed that life had but one
>   purpose—to learn.

Dose it mean: while he was a teenager or while he reached in young age.(at beging of young age)?

Comment: Where did this quote come from? (See [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source?r=SearchResults&s=1|33.7678) on meta.)

Answer (score 1):

*'still very young'* is figurative and it denotes that the age for a particular person is *not a proper age for something*. This has least to do with 'numbers.'

Check-

> He was too young to die

He could be 45 which is not the age to say goodbye to the world!

Likewise,

> He is still very young to consume alcohol

He is not an adult; his internal body organs are not yet mature.

So, in your case, *he was sent away to study* means it is not the age someone would send their child away from them. That was a tender age wherein a kid requires to be with its parents.

Comment: I would clarify that "too young" would mean that the writer/speaker would think that anyone would agree, that they are clearly younger than is acceptable, while "still very young" can mean not so young as "too young", but still younger than many people would be entirely comfortable with, or at least younger than most would expect.